# Use ansible_user variable in ansible_user variable

Tags: ansible

As described in the [ansible documentation for routeros](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/routeros/docsite/ssh-guide.html#important-notes) I need to add `+cet512w` to my ansible_user. But I do not want to hardcode the user in every routeros play[book] so I use `{{ ansible_user }}` everywhere. Is it possible to concat that `+cet512w` string to the ansible_user variable in only the routeros play[book]s by setting the variable? Or would it be somehow possible to concat it in group_vars or in inventory? If yes, then how?

following does not work:

```
- name: RouterOS - my playbook
  hosts: routeros
  vars:
    - ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
    - ansible_network_os: community.network.routeros
    - ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user + '+cet512w' }}"
```

and gives this error msg:
`FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ ansible_user }} + '+cet512w''. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ ansible_user }} + '+cet512w''. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: An unhandled exception...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it into the *pre_tasks*

```yaml
- hosts: all

  pre_tasks:

    - set_fact:
        ansible_user: "{{ (ansible_connection == 'ansible.netcommon.network_cli')|
                          ternary(ansible_user ~ '+cet512w', ansible_user) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ansible_user
```

For example, given the below inventory

```ini
[test]
host_A
router_A

[test:vars]
ansible_user=admin

[routers]
router_A

[routers:vars]
ansible_connection=ansible.netcommon.network_cli
ansible_network_os=community.network.routeros
```

The play gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [host_A] => 
  ansible_user: admin
ok: [router_A] => 
  ansible_user: admin+cet512w
```